# How to Configure using STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider in spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I am using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis, version: 2.0.2.RELEASE.

I was able to successfully use binder and access it locally using the default ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration mentioned in the KinesisBinderConfiguration.

Now I know this set-up wont work for me because,
The Kinesis data stream is in AWS account 1
The Service is running in AWS account 2
(I have already done the setup of assumed Role so that Account 2 can access streams in account 1 using the assumed role)

However I am not sure how can I override the credentials in binder to use STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KinesisBinderConfiguration` is fully based on the auto-configuration from the Spring Cloud AWS, which provides for us a `ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration` and expose an `AWSCredentialsProvider` bean under the `credentialsProvider` name if not present yet.

So, probably you just need to have your `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` as a bean in your configuration class and give it that `credentialsProvider` bean name.

Comment: thanks! got it working by adding the following bean:
`@Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(roleArn, roleSession).build();
    }`